# dato de oracle llega incompleto

Tags: php, oracle

Hola tengo un problema con una consulta de oracle, tengo un campo que trae fecha y hora juntas pero al momento de hacer la consulta desde php me corta la hora y solo imprime la fecha

Esta es mi consulta y quiero a.dtmhorarequisicion, en la base esta completo el campo pero cuando la imprimo en php solo trae la fecha

```
$resultado = oci_parse($conn, "SELECT a.numnumrequisicion, a.dtmhorarequisicion, a.vchestatusrequis, a.chrdestino, a.biturgente, b.vchdescripcion, c.vchapellidopaterno, c.vchapellidomaterno, c.vchnombre
FROM ivrequisicionmaestro a, nodepartamento b, noempleado c WHERE a.smicvedeptoalmacen = 3 AND a.smicvedeptorequis = b.smicvedepartamento AND a.intcveemplearequis = c.intcveempleado AND a.dtmfecharequisicion BETWEEN TO_DATE ('$fechadebusqueda 00:00:00', 'yyyy/mm/dd HH24:MI:SS') AND TO_DATE('$fechadebusqueda 23:59:59', 'yyyy/mm/dd HH24:MI:SS')
ORDER BY a.numnumrequisicion DESC");
oci_execute($resultado);

while (($r = oci_fetch_array($resultado, OCI_BOTH)) != false) {
$fec= $r[1];

}
echo $fec;
```

Comment: al momento de hacer `$fec = $r[1]` esta asignando y sobrescribiendo la variable por cada iteracion

Comment: Entonces como podría acceder al resultado de la consulta para traer el dato completo?